# How to handle JPA entities in EJB beans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

Regularly in a non-JavaEE application, I would create some sort of persistence-facade/persistence layer (located in a folder containing all persistence handling code). Since I just started with JavaEE I don't understand what is the best way to create that "layer":

- Should I use the same Persistence facade/interface and create an EJB from it?
- Should I create and EJB for each entity (e.g an EJB for Employee and
  EJB for Department)?
- How to separate the code to projects/folders? what does the client
  side needs to "know" from the server side code? should the entities
  be in a separate "common" project that will be used by server &
  client?
- ...

It would be great if you could help me sort it out, or even point me to the right manual.

Comment: Typical "I understand the API, but I don't understand the problem domain" type of questions, a state you get in when you follow tutorials and/or look at existing code and not read a book which puts the information in a proper context for you. I can't explain this stuff here, it really does fill a whole book.

Comment: @GáborBakos I guess you're right.

Comment: @Gimby I would appreciate if you could point me to the right book instead.

Comment: I can't because its not like I'm going to keep reading books on the topics I already know, the books I read are quite old. But Amazon user reviews have never steered me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

EJB3 introdice EntityManager  which takes control entities. EntityManager inject into busness logic service (stateless EJB ) and takes over management entity. No need to create a façade for each entity class, but if you need you can make separate services for each entity class. More details and example see in book "Thinking in Enterprise Java 
by Bruce Eckel"